# Magento Custom Module won't show in Admin - What am I overlooking?

Tags: xml, magento, magento-1.8

Hello All & thanks in advance!  ***New to This***

I have been racking my head trying to discover why both my module and admin options won't show in Magento's backend.  I have tried adding adminhtml.xml info, tweeking my config.xml & system.xml files, but no cigar.  I had a look at another stackoverflow thread found here, but it didn't seem to solve my need.
[Magento system.xml and 404 error when trying to access the configuration panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422883/magento-system-xml-and-404-error-when-trying-to-access-the-configuration-panel)

I attempted to follow the following guides:

http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2012/01/30/add-custom-settings-in-magento-admin-panel/

and some of my own digging in to create my module, but it just wont show up.  I have cleared var/session and var/cache manually, log out and back in, flushed & refreshed cache several times.  This leads me to think I have an error somewhere.  A fresh pair of eyes is best, so please have a look!  Thanks in advance!

PB_Modules.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
    -<config>
        -<modules>
            -<Pbmodule_Remindorder>
                <active>true</active>
                <codePool>local</codePool>
            </Pbmodule_Remindorder>
        </modules>
    </config>
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Pbmodule_Remindorder>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Pbmodule_Remindorder>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <remindorder>
                <class>Pbmodule_Remindorder_Model</class>
            </remindorder>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <remindorder>
                <class>Pbmodule_Remindorder_Helper</class>
            </remindorder>
        </helpers>
        <template>
            <email>
                <pbmodule_order_reminder_vendors_email_template translate="label" module="remindorder">
                    <label>PB - Vendor Order Reminder Email</label>
                    <file>quote/remindorder.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </pbmodule_order_reminder_vendors_email_template>
            </email>
        </template>
     </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <system>
                            <children>
                                <config>
                                    <children>
                                        <remindorder_options>
                                            <title>PB Extensions - All</title>
                                        </remindorder_options>
                                    </children>
                                </config>
                            </children>
                        </system>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </adminhtml>

    -<crontab>
        -<jobs>
            -<pbmodule_remindorder>
                -<schedule>
                    <cron_expr>0 7 * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                -<run>
                    <model>remindorder/observer::pbpendingshipments</model>
                </run>
            </pbmodule_remindorder>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<config>
    <tabs>
        <pb_modules1 translate="label" module="remindorder">
            <label>PurchaseBlack Extensions</label>
            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
        </pb_modules1>
    </tabs>
    -<sections>
        -<remindorder_options translate="label" module="remindorder">
                    <label>Vendor Order Reminder Options</label>
                    <tab>pb_modules1</tab>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <groups>
                            <order_reminder translate="label" module="remindorder">
                                <label>Vendor Order Reminder Settings</label>
                                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                                <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>    
                                -<fields>
                                    -<ready_status translate="label">
                                        <label>Send Vendor Reminder on the following statuses</label>
                                        <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
                                        <source_model>pbmodel/source</source_model>
                                        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                        <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
                                        <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                                    </ready_status>
                                    -<notify_in_days translate="label">
                                        <label>Delay in days to send FIRST "Email Order Follow up emails"</label>
                                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                                        <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                        <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
                                        <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>

                                    </notify_in_days>
                                    -<notify_in_days2 translate="label">
                                        <label>Delay in days to send Last "Email Order Follow up emails"</label>
                                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                                        <sort_order>25</sort_order>
                                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                        <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
                                        <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>

                                    </notify_in_days2>
                                    -<vendors_email_template translate="label">
                                        <label>Vendor Order Notification Template</label>
                                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_email_template</source_model>
                                        <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                                    </vendors_email_template>
                                </fields>
                            </order_reminder>
                        </groups>
        </remindorder_options>
    </sections>
</config>
```

adminhtml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <system>
                    <children>
                        <config>
                            <children>
                                <remindorder_options translate="title" module="remindorder">
                                    <title>RemindOrder</title>
                                </remindorder_options>
                            </children>
                        </config>
                    </children>
                </system>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</config>
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?  Thanks StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that the file in app/etc/modules is not named correctly. If i am not mistaken, it should be named like the actual module, so rename the file in app/etc/modules to **Pbmodule_Remindorder.xml** and check again if the module comes up in your config.

Comment: Cool.  I'll rename that XML file and see what's going on.  Thanks for the suggestion!  I thought that XML could have any name.

Comment: Seems like this made it happen for me!  Now I have to find a way to get it to do what it should!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the folder structure of your module?
Also, is the module showing at all under System->Config->Advanced? If not, then you should check your xml file in /app/etc/modules. Maybe it is just a copy&paste error, but if you have a tab or spaces in that xml fil before the xml header (like visible in your question), try removing that.

Comment: I can not see my custom module in System > Config > Advanced either.  It does not show up unfortunately.  My folder structure is as follows

`app/etc/modules/PB_Modules.xml
app/code/local/Pbmodule/Remindorder/etc/config.xml
app/code/local/Pbmodule/Remindorder/etc/system.xml
app/code/local/Pbmodule/Remindorder/etc/adminhtml.xml
app/code/local/Pbmodule/Remindorder/Model/Observer.php
app/code/local/Pbmodule/Remindorder/Model/Source.php
app/code/local/Pbmodule/Remindorder/Helper/Data.php`

I will check all file for spaces & tabs and cross my fingers!